# Vue 2.6.0 - How to use the new slot syntax to render slot content to children component's named slot

Tags: vue.js

To understand my question, look at this pseudo code:

```
<my-tooltip-wrapper>
  <some-slot-content />
</my-tooltip-wrapper
```

`MyTooltipWrapper` contains a `TooltipComponent` from a package. However, this needs another slot to show my `<some-slot-content />`

To see [this as an example](https://jsfiddle.net/56e2jr79/1/) where the old syntax is used, please have a look and try to use the new syntax.

Before the slot-syntax change I could just use it like this:

```
//inside of MyTooltipWrapper
<tooltip-component>
   <slot
      name="reference"
      slot="reference"
   />
</tooltip-component>
```

However, how would you change it into the new syntax? I tried this, but it didn't work:

```
<template #reference>
  <slot
    name="reference"
  />
</template>
```

Comment: I saw your example and it's working.

Comment: @roliroli Sorry for the misunderstanding, this example works with the old syntax, please try it with the new one...

Comment: I think the bug has been fixed with: https://github.com/vuejs/vue/commit/57bc80a546acb2bd092edd393228324b453ae4e2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A similar question was questioned [here](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/9452#issuecomment-461521448)

And it was fixed with the latest [commit](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/commit/57bc80a546acb2bd092edd393228324b453ae4e2)

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/a8q09cfh/

```
<slot-owner>
  <template v-slot:reference>
      Hello world
  </template>
</slot-owner>


Vue.component('slot-owner', {
  template: `
     <div>
        <slot name="reference" />
     </div>
  `
});
```

Comment: Could you please use my fiddle, because your answer does not help at all...

Comment: element-ui does not support vue-2.6 slot-syntax yet: https://github.com/ElemeFE/element/issues/14309

Comment: that is weird, because I thought it does not matter in my case since I don't need to render something in element. I just need to "redirect" the slot to elements slot...